# Why maps iterator is showing base operand invalid error?

Tags: c++, pointers, dictionary

So I try to make a map and then choose its begin() as first iterator position. Then I try to use it in a range based for loop. Have a look at this code here:

```
long int lilysHomework(map<long int,long int>& a,int n,map<long int,long int>& p) 

{
    long int c=0;
    map<long int,long int>::iterator pos;
    pos=p.begin();
    for(auto& elem : a)
    {
        if((pos->second)!=(elem->first)) //fix this part
            c++;
        pos++;
    }
    c--;
    cout << c;
    return c;
}
```

but in 6th line i get an error saying base operator has non pointer type. I am aware that the iterator returns always the address so it should have been able to get dereferenced. Can someone please help me out?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you use here is `range_for` since c++11,see [range-based for](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)  ,so it directly operates on the `value_type` of `map`,which is `std::pair<const Key, T>`,not the `std::map::iterator`.

In your case,you can use the **structured binding declaration** since c++17

```
for (auto&& [first,second] : mymap) {
    // use first and second
}
```

Or just use the

```
for(auto it=mymap.begin();it!=mymap.end();++it)
{
   /* do something*/
}
```

Here you can use `it` as an iterator and use the operator `->`.

Answer (score 2):

```
for(auto& elem : a)
```

does not make `elem` an iterator. It make `elem` a `std::map::value_type`.

Use

```
if ( (pos->second) != (elem.first) ) { ... }
```